# Exporting a layout class to a general class

Tags: android

I have this code that creates a dynamic layout when a floating button is pressed.

This code works flawless but I want to put this code in a class so I can call it to do the same job but instead of copying this code in every view I want it, I want to call it instead from which view I need for.

This is the code

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class tabTueActivity extends Fragment {

    int i;

    LinearLayout layoutNewEvent, linearLayoutEventText, linearLayoutEventVoyage, linearLayoutEventIndicator, eventLayout;

    ImageView imageViewEventFrom, imageViewEventTo, imageViewSearch, imageViewStart;

    TextView textViewEventFrom, textViewEventTo;

    FloatingActionButton createEvent;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_tue_frag, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);

        eventLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.event_layout);
        createEvent = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_event_button);

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutNewEventParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                layoutNewEventParams.setMargins(40, 20, 40, 10);
                layoutNewEventParams.height = 150;

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutEventTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutEventIndicatorParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewEventFromParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                imageViewEventFromParams.setMargins(0,0,0,10);
                imageViewEventFromParams.weight = (float) 0.5;

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewEventToParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                imageViewEventToParams.weight = (float) 0.5;

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutEventVoyageParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                linearLayoutEventVoyageParams.weight = 1;

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewEventFromParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewEventToParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewSearchParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        final   LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewStartParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


        createEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final LinearLayout layoutNewEvent = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                final LinearLayout linearLayoutEventText = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                final LinearLayout linearLayoutEventIndicator = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                final LinearLayout linearLayoutEventVoyage = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                final ImageView imageViewEventFrom = new ImageView(getActivity());
                final ImageView imageViewEventTo = new ImageView(getActivity());
                final ImageView imageViewSearch = new ImageView(getActivity());
                final ImageView imageViewStart = new ImageView(getActivity());
                final TextView textViewEventTo = new TextView(getActivity());
                final TextView textViewEventFrom = new TextView(getActivity());

                i++;

                Log.e("EVENT BUTTON", "New event created.....");

                layoutNewEvent.setId(i);
                layoutNewEvent.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.eventColor));
                layoutNewEvent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                linearLayoutEventText.setId(i);
                linearLayoutEventText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Log.e("LAYOUT EVENT","Layout Event Pressed.....");

                    }
                });

                linearLayoutEventText.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                linearLayoutEventText.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutEventTextParams);

                linearLayoutEventIndicator.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                linearLayoutEventIndicator.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutEventIndicatorParams);

                linearLayoutEventVoyage.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                linearLayoutEventVoyage.setPadding(10,5,10,5);
                linearLayoutEventVoyage.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutEventVoyageParams);

                imageViewEventFrom.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor3));
                imageViewEventFrom.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageViewEventFrom.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up_white);
                imageViewEventFrom.setLayoutParams(imageViewEventFromParams);

                imageViewEventTo.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor2));
                imageViewEventTo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageViewEventTo.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down_white);
                imageViewEventTo.setLayoutParams(imageViewEventToParams);

                textViewEventFrom.setText("San Pawl Il Bahar");
                textViewEventFrom.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
                textViewEventFrom.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT);
                textViewEventFrom.setTextSize(20);
                textViewEventFrom.setMaxLines(1);
                textViewEventFrom.setLayoutParams(textViewEventFromParams);

                textViewEventTo.setText("Zonqor");
                textViewEventTo.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
                textViewEventTo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT);
                textViewEventTo.setTextSize(20);
                textViewEventTo.setMaxLines(1);
                textViewEventTo.setLayoutParams(textViewEventToParams);

                imageViewSearch.setId(i);
                imageViewSearch.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor2));
                imageViewSearch.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageViewSearch.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_white);
                imageViewSearch.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                imageViewSearch.setLayoutParams(imageViewSearchParams);
                imageViewSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Log.e("SEARCH EVENT","Search Button Pressed.....");

                    }
                });

                imageViewStart.setId(i);
                imageViewStart.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor4));
                imageViewStart.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageViewStart.setImageResource(R.drawable.start_white);
                imageViewStart.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                imageViewStart.setLayoutParams(imageViewStartParams);
                imageViewStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Log.e("START EVENT", "Start Event Pressed.....");
                    }
                });



                linearLayoutEventIndicator.addView(imageViewEventFrom);
                linearLayoutEventIndicator.addView(imageViewEventTo);
                linearLayoutEventVoyage.addView(textViewEventFrom);
                linearLayoutEventVoyage.addView(textViewEventTo);
                linearLayoutEventText.addView(linearLayoutEventIndicator);
                linearLayoutEventText.addView(linearLayoutEventVoyage);
                layoutNewEvent.addView(linearLayoutEventText);
                layoutNewEvent.addView(imageViewSearch);
                layoutNewEvent.addView(imageViewStart);

                eventLayout.addView(layoutNewEvent, layoutNewEventParams);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any clue on how to do this ?

Below is the code I want to put in a separate class

```
  createEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final LinearLayout layoutNewEvent = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            final LinearLayout linearLayoutEventText = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            final LinearLayout linearLayoutEventIndicator = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            final LinearLayout linearLayoutEventVoyage = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            final ImageView imageViewEventFrom = new ImageView(getActivity());
            final ImageView imageViewEventTo = new ImageView(getActivity());
            final ImageView imageViewSearch = new ImageView(getActivity());
            final ImageView imageViewStart = new ImageView(getActivity());
            final TextView textViewEventTo = new TextView(getActivity());
            final TextView textViewEventFrom = new TextView(getActivity());

            i++;

            Log.e("EVENT BUTTON", "New event created.....");

            layoutNewEvent.setId(i);
            layoutNewEvent.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.eventColor));
            layoutNewEvent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            linearLayoutEventText.setId(i);
            linearLayoutEventText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Log.e("LAYOUT EVENT","Layout Event Pressed.....");

                }
            });

            linearLayoutEventText.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linearLayoutEventText.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutEventTextParams);

            linearLayoutEventIndicator.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            linearLayoutEventIndicator.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutEventIndicatorParams);

            linearLayoutEventVoyage.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            linearLayoutEventVoyage.setPadding(10,5,10,5);
            linearLayoutEventVoyage.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutEventVoyageParams);

            imageViewEventFrom.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor3));
            imageViewEventFrom.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageViewEventFrom.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up_white);
            imageViewEventFrom.setLayoutParams(imageViewEventFromParams);

            imageViewEventTo.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor2));
            imageViewEventTo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageViewEventTo.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down_white);
            imageViewEventTo.setLayoutParams(imageViewEventToParams);

            textViewEventFrom.setText("San Pawl Il Bahar");
            textViewEventFrom.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
            textViewEventFrom.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT);
            textViewEventFrom.setTextSize(20);
            textViewEventFrom.setMaxLines(1);
            textViewEventFrom.setLayoutParams(textViewEventFromParams);

            textViewEventTo.setText("Zonqor");
            textViewEventTo.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
            textViewEventTo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT);
            textViewEventTo.setTextSize(20);
            textViewEventTo.setMaxLines(1);
            textViewEventTo.setLayoutParams(textViewEventToParams);

            imageViewSearch.setId(i);
            imageViewSearch.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor2));
            imageViewSearch.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageViewSearch.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_white);
            imageViewSearch.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
            imageViewSearch.setLayoutParams(imageViewSearchParams);
            imageViewSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Log.e("SEARCH EVENT","Search Button Pressed.....");

                }
            });

            imageViewStart.setId(i);
            imageViewStart.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor4));
            imageViewStart.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageViewStart.setImageResource(R.drawable.start_white);
            imageViewStart.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
            imageViewStart.setLayoutParams(imageViewStartParams);
            imageViewStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Log.e("START EVENT", "Start Event Pressed.....");
                }
            });



            linearLayoutEventIndicator.addView(imageViewEventFrom);
            linearLayoutEventIndicator.addView(imageViewEventTo);
            linearLayoutEventVoyage.addView(textViewEventFrom);
            linearLayoutEventVoyage.addView(textViewEventTo);
            linearLayoutEventText.addView(linearLayoutEventIndicator);
            linearLayoutEventText.addView(linearLayoutEventVoyage);
            layoutNewEvent.addView(linearLayoutEventText);
            layoutNewEvent.addView(imageViewSearch);
            layoutNewEvent.addView(imageViewStart);

            eventLayout.addView(layoutNewEvent, layoutNewEventParams);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You're making life MUCH harder on yourself that it needs to be.  Put the layout you want to create dynamically into an xml layout file and inflate it rather than intiializing it by dozens of methods calls.  This entire thing can be reduced to 1 xml file, 2 lines of code, and a few extra lines to set on click listeners.  Basically if you ever use new to create more than 1 view at a time, you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an anonymous class

> createEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

you can create the class explicitly. A more informative answer would require more details about what kinds of views you want to pass in. If they all have the same format than it isn't really a problem but if some have variable numbers of subviews then you might want to look into creating an abstract view and subclassing it when needed and altering the shared logic for the view.

Really though you should be looking to do this in XML and not programatically.

Comment: All the views will be the same and the objects will be created inside a tab view.